# Change the value of the all the element in a list using for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to renew the element in a list by using for loop. Here the code.

```
x = 90
y = 84
z = 32
list1 = [x, y, z]
for i in list1:
    i = 45

print(list1)
```

However, this doesn't work as I expected, i.e. it doesn't print out `[45,45,45]`.
Why is that? And what's the solution other than making a slice to create a new list.

Comment: You need to use something like `for i in range(len(list`)):`, then `list[i] = 45`.

Comment: You could use a single liner: `list1 = [45 for num in list1]`

Comment: Is there any more ways other than list comprehension, loop , list methods and slicing ? @Simon

Comment: Not that I know of,  all these answers just about wrap it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are storing list values one by one in variable `i` and then reassigning `i` itself. `i` has the same value with the list element but they are totally different. Reassigning it does not change the list.

Instead try iterating over the list using indexes and reassign the list element itself in the place.

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]

for i in range(len(list1)):
    list1[i] = 45

print(list1)
# [45, 45, 45]
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
list = [12,43,24]
for n,i in enumerate(list):
    list[n] = 45

print(list) #[45, 45, 45]
```

"This is wrong ->" Because when you do for i in ... you work with copy of list

Comment: *"you work with copy of list"* <- nope. Not even close. No copies of *anything* are involved there. The problem is simply that rebinding the `i` variable doesn't update the list.

Comment: Sorry. My mistake. Edit answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative, simpler solution to achieve what you want, by adding a new variable count which is used to keep track of the index positions to update within the list/array:

```
x = 90
y = 84
z = 32

list1 = [x, y, z]
count = 0

for i in list1:
    list1[count] = 45
    count+=1

print(list1)    #output result = [45, 45, 45]
```